# Assign foreground color property to a string dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a label and i assigned foreground color to it dynamically using the following code:

```
string xCol = "#F8951D";
Color c = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(xCol);
string abc = Convert.ToString(c);
string[] col = abc.Split();
for (int k = 1; k <= 4; k++)
{
    col[k] = col[k].Replace("A", "");
    col[k] = col[k].Replace("=", "");
    col[k] = col[k].Replace("[", "");
    col[k] = col[k].Replace(",", "");
    col[k] = col[k].Replace("R", "");
    col[k] = col[k].Replace("G", "");
    col[k] = col[k].Replace("B", "");
    col[k] = col[k].Replace("]", "");
    if (k == 1)
    { int abc1 = Convert.ToInt32(col[k]); Session["abc1"] = abc1; }
    else if (k == 2)
    { int abc2 = Convert.ToInt32(col[k]); Session["abc2"] = abc2; }
    else if (k == 3)
    { int abc3 = Convert.ToInt32(col[k]); Session["abc3"] = abc3; }
    else if (k == 4)
    { int abc4 = Convert.ToInt32(col[k]); Session["abc4"] = abc4; }
}

int c1 = Convert.ToInt32(Session["abc1"].ToString());
int c2 = Convert.ToInt32(Session["abc2"].ToString());
int c3 = Convert.ToInt32(Session["abc3"].ToString());
int c4 = Convert.ToInt32(Session["abc4"].ToString());
lblDept.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(c1,c2,c3,c4);
```

How can I assign a foreground color property to a string dynamically using `a,r,g,b` components?

Is it possible to assign it using `string strColor = Color.FromArgb(c1,c2,c3,c4);`?
How can I set a color property to a string dynamically?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What _exactly_ are you having difficulties with?

Comment: i want to assign color to a string dynamically(in code).

Comment: Once again: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to assign a color to a `string`, a .NET `string` is a data type which contains no formatting but only a collection on chars that can be used to render some text. Your question is like assigning a font to an integer, an integer `int` only contains digits, like 1 or 150, no other attributes.

Said so, if in the user interface of your application (Windows Based or Web Based) you want to render some text using a specific `Font` ( so character family, like Arial, size, and color ), you should use a UI control like a label or a TextBox which usually allows you to set the text content in a `.Text` property and allows you to also manipulate the style by using other properties. But such UI control is not a string, is a container of some logic and graphics which serves to render strings with a specific formatting.